# How many active users maximum does a Parse.com database allow on the free plan?

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am exploring Parse.com and building a proof-of-concept web application using the Parse.com data storage. I keep receiving a Daily App Stats email. That's OK, and I noticed one of my database applications had 8 ACTIVE USERS and it reported 14% of Monthly quote. I tried to search around Parse.com for its meaning but didn't get anything.

My question is how many users at maximum a database can handle on the free plan? My app will have as many as 300+ users.

Comment: I don't think it has anything (or much) to do with the number of users,m it with the data throughput. If y have a look at there [pricing](https://parse.com/plans) plane, you will see that you will be restricted to 30 requests per second and 2tb of data transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading of the pricing and FAQ pages is that you are not accounted based on the number of users you have.  Rather you are accounted based on your aggregate requests per second, file storage, database storage and data transfer.

The FAQ has this advice:

> Q: Does requests per second roughly translate to # of concurrent users? I anticipate millions of users but I can't afford to pay $10M per month.
>
> A: Generally when your user count doubles, your requests per second also double. However, different apps send different numbers of requests per second depending on how frequently they save objects or issue queries. We estimate that the average app's active user will issue 10 requests. Thus, if you had a million users on a particular day, and their traffic was evenly spread throughout the day, you could estimate your app would need about 10,000,000 total API requests, or about 120 requests per second. Every app is different, so we strongly encourage you to measure how many requests your users send. You can see this in the Performance Analytics tab of your account.

So ....

> My question is how many users at maximum a database can handle on the free plan? My app will have as many as 300+ users.

There is no limit the number of users, but if you have lots of simultaneous active users that is likely to translate into lots of requests per second.  The actual ratio depends on your application and what your users are doing.  That is impossible for us to predict.

However, if 8 active users takes about 15% of the allowed free usage, then a simple linear extrapolation says that are liable to need to start paying for capacity when you reach about 50 to 60 users.  But that is little better than a guess .... and it takes no account of how evenly the usage is spread over a typical 24 hour period.